# Remove screens from stack navigator in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I have a use case with the following flow:
Dashboard->AddProductScreen1.0->AddProductScreen2.0-> product details screen

These screens are inside a stack navigator

Add Product screen is a multi-page form to fill details of the product. On  AddProductScreen2.0 when clicking on AddProduct button, API call will be made to save product. If call is successful we will move to ProductDetailsScreen. At this point I want to remove the AddProductScreens from the stack navigator so that on click of back button we move to Dashboard rather than the AddProductScreens again

How can this be done in react native?

Comment: Hi @IN_DEV, feel free to have a look at all answers and mark the best answer for your question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of is that you can use [replace](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#replace) instead of push/navigate when you move from Screen1 to Screen2 and to details screen, if you need to navigate from screen2 to screen1 you can override backbutton action also to use replace. The second option is to [pop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#pop) / [popToTop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#poptotop) on the second screen and then navigate to details.

Example:

```ts
useEffect(() => {
        if (newCreatedTaskId) {
            navigation.pop();
            navigation.replace('UpdateTaskMembers', {
                id: newCreatedTaskId,
                newTask: true,
            });
        }
    }, [newCreatedTaskId, navigation]);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE (Sample not tested)

Just found a new method in `react-navigation@5.7+`,
**the benefits** of this method should be that you don't need to override the `HeaderBackButton`, `Android Back button`, and `Back Swipe Gesture` by yourself.

Feel free to try it and **tell me the result** if your `react-navigation` version is high enough:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const ProductDetailsScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
      /* Prevent default behavior of leaving the screen */
      e.preventDefault();

      /* Pop to the first screen of stack navigator - DashboardScreen */
      navigation.popToTop();
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return (<>{/* Your screen content here */}</>);
};

export default ProductDetailsScreen;
```

Method reference docs:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/

---

#### Original Answer

As what you want is to let users go back to `DashboardScreen` in `ProductDetailsScreen` when clicking the header back button, please try to achieve it by overriding the header back button's function like below:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { HeaderBackButton } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const ProductDetailsScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => (<HeaderBackButton onPress={backToDashboard} />)
    });

    /* Remember to override Android system back button */
    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backToDashboard);

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, [navigation]);

  /* As your first screen in stack navigator is DashboardScreen so just popToTop() */
  const backToDashboard = () => { navigation.popToTop(); };

  return (<>{/* Your screen content here */}</>);
};

export default ProductDetailsScreen;
```

**NOTES: Remember to override Android back button behavior (as in sample).

If you have gesture handler in your screen, remember to also override it**

---

More information on overriding header back button:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/#overriding-the-back-button
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headerleft